# Understanding the Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $P(x,u) = \dfrac{e^{-u} u^x}{x!}$ be a random variable. I understand the $u$ is the mean average of success, and $x$ is the random variable. So, how come when I assign $x=x$ $P(x,u)$ is significantly lower then $1$?
If I sell two cars per day on average, my chances of selling two cars tomorrow should be pretty good right? Instead I got $P(2,2) = 0.2706$.

Would anyone care to explain? Thanks!

P.S. I was looking for a guide on how to write mathematical symbols here, but I couldn't find anything. Any links provided would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The expected value is an average value.  Some days you sell fewer than two cars, other days you sell 2 or more cars. On *average*, you sell 2 cars per day. But this does not imply that you sell exactly two cars per day most of the time. Here, there is a small,  but significant, probability that you sell a large number of cars on a given day, which brings the average up.

As you found, around  27% of days, you sell *exactly* two cars.  You can calculate that around 64% of days, you sell 0 or 1 cars. That leaves 9% of days where you sell more than 2 cars; and that "drives" the average number of cars sold per day up (to 2).

Comment: To expand on this: to sell on average 2.64 cars per day is not to sell exactly 2.64 cars during a day. In fact, one **never** sells exactly 2.64 cars during a given day.